# Dialogbox gives error on .show() in android gingerbread version

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-dialogfragment, android-2.3-gingerbread, fragmentmanager

I have to implement multiple select dialog box for gingerbread version.

My main Activity called EventCreateActivity extends class called BaseActivity and that extends SherlockActivity.

main activity

```
public class EventCreateActivity extends BaseActivity implements OfferDialogFragment.OfferDialogListner{
```

within main activity i called for dialog as follows, but it gives an error on newFragment.show method called "The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type EventCreateActivity". OfferDialogFragment class has extends dialogFragment class.

```
DialogFragment newFragment = new OfferDialogFragment();     
Bundle databndle = new Bundle();
boolean offerArr [] = vip.getBooleanOffers(include_offer.getText().toString());
databndle.putBooleanArray("BOOL_OFFERS_ARRAY", offerArr);
newFragment.setArguments(databndle);                        
newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "OfferDialogFragment");
```

it would be grate if anyone give me a help to solve this. thanks in advance!

Edit 01: here is entire code of EventCreateActivity

```
public class EventCreateActivity extends BaseActivity implements  OfferDialogFragment.OfferDialogListner{

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
       // set date picker as current date
       return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, 
                     year, month,day);         
    case OFFER_DIALOG_ID: 

        DialogFragment newFragment = new OfferDialogFragment();

        Bundle databndle = new Bundle();
        boolean offerArr [] = vip.getBooleanOffers(include_offer.getText().toString());
        databndle.putBooleanArray("BOOL_OFFERS_ARRAY", offerArr);
        newFragment.setArguments(databndle);            

        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "OfferDialogFragment");

        return onCreateDialog(id);
    }
```

}

// OfferDialogFragment Class

```
public class OfferDialogFragment extends SherlockDialogFragment{

public interface OfferDialogListner{
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog, ArrayList<Integer> selected);
    public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);
}

OfferDialogListner mOfferDialogListner;

@Override
public void onAttach(android.app.Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try{
        mOfferDialogListner = (OfferDialogListner) activity;
    }catch(ClassCastException e){
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OfferDialogListner");
    }
};

@Override   
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    final ArrayList<Integer> mSelectedOfferItems = new ArrayList<Integer>();        

    boolean [] selectOfferItems = getArguments().getBooleanArray("BOOL_OFFERS_ARRAY");
        // add array data to arrayalist
    if(selectOfferItems[0]){                
        mSelectedOfferItems.add(0);
    }
    if(selectOfferItems[1]){                
        mSelectedOfferItems.add(1);
    }
    if(selectOfferItems[2]){                
        mSelectedOfferItems.add(2);
    }           
    if(selectOfferItems[3]){                
        mSelectedOfferItems.add(3);
    }   

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    builder.setTitle(R.string.artist_offer_tv)
            .setMultiChoiceItems(R.array.offer_items, selectOfferItems, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {

                    if(isChecked){
                        mSelectedOfferItems.add(which);                         

                    }else{
                        mSelectedOfferItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(which));
                    }

                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.string_ok , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    Integer[] selected = mSelectedOfferItems.toArray(new Integer[mSelectedOfferItems.size()]);


                               mOfferDialogListner.onDialogPositiveClick(OfferDialogFragment.this, mSelectedOfferItems);
                }
            })

            .setNegativeButton(R.string.string_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    mOfferDialogListner.onDialogNegativeClick(OfferDialogFragment.this);
                }
            });

    return builder.create();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getSupportFragmentManager` doesn't exist in `SherlockActivity` - you want to use `getFragmentManager` instead.

Comment: hi Dave, yes. then error says "The method show(FragmentManager, String) in the type DialogFragment is not applicable for the arguments (FragmentManager, String)"

Comment: Is your dialog extending from `SherlockDialogFragment`?

Comment: no. it extends DialogFragment, even though changed to SherlockDialogFragment, error is stil there. it says "The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type EventCreateActivity"

Comment: Whoops, yes - since you're using fragments, your Activity should extend from `SherlockFragmentActivity` then! (been a while since I used Sherlock)

Comment: Not any success yet. I will put whole code, some time it will help u guy to solve this.

Comment: Finally i found you are right! "your Activity should extend from SherlockFragmentActivity then!"